# Hyper-V network dies after a few days of uptime

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, hp, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have a Hyper-V server that randomly just drops off the internet in no specific pattern. It will go fine running five VMs that all have their own IPV4 in a /29 subnet.

The host machine is on a separate /30. Every few days at random times the host and all the virtual machines will lose network connectivity.

I have had the datacenter connect a KVM to the machine and I could not revive the networking without a reboot. This is very annoying and I don't know why it would be happening.

The server is a HP Proliant SE1101. The host OS is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: NIC firmware and drivers?

Answer (score 1):

There was a known issue with HyperV VMs dropping their network connection under high load scenarios. I would recommend to install SP1 along with the latest Windows Updates and the latest network drivers.